# LruCache returning wrong bitmaps for specified key

Tags: android, bitmap, android-bitmap, android-lru-cache

I am very new to Android development.

I am running into issues getting the correct bitmap from my LruBitmapCache. I use the UUID to generate a unique Id, I don't use a URL because I am generating the bitmap on a canvas. (I'm copying `getDrawingCache()` from my view to a new bitmap (using copy) then storing the copy into the cache).

For some reason after I store a bitmap, when I access it, it ends up being a bitmap for another id ... this happens sometimes. Any ideas?

I use a currentIndex to track which position I am at in the cachedKeys Array (I want to sequentially save and navigate through the bitamp on a canvas). I think I'm updating the entry in the cache wrong...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A fellow developer assisted. I was doing  `mDrawingView.restartDrawingCache();` incorrectly and in the wrong order.

It should have been:

```
<drawing view>.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
Bitmap mmap= <drawing view>.getDrawingCache();
Bitmap copy = mmap.copy(mmap.getConfig(), false);
<drawing view>.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
```

Cheers, maybe this will help someone out :)